# How to show send response as chunks to frontend from Nodejs using Express?

Tags: node.js, axios, callback, stream, progress-bar

I'm trying to build a functionality where multiple things happen in a single API Request.

**Step 1.** File Gets Added to S3 Bucket

**Step 2.** File gets encoded

**Step 3.** Update Few Records in Database

I'm able to send the response to Front end after all the 3 steps are completed.

But, I need to show progress bar during Step 1 in Front end

Custom Loader messages during Step 2

Job Completed popup after Step 3.

How do I continuously listen to server events or callbacks?

I'm using VueJS in the front end to make the API request using Axios.

I'm using NodeJS with express in the backend.

I have looked at [progress-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-stream) npm package, but I found it confusing on how to use it with express.

How do I create a progressEvent with custom status like - Pending, In progress (progress percentage), Completed?

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: One approach can be using a web-socket (socket.io) connection. For each step you will notify the ui/frontend with socket message. You might not hold http connection this long.

Comment: @ShamsNahid I felt sockets would be overkill, could you suggest any other alternative?

Comment: Without web-socket, we can not directly send a response to ui. So using http connection, an approach could be making continuous API call with certain seconds delay and send the response accordingly. For example, making the call in 2 seconds intervals and repeat until the operation is completed.